# components of population change at block group level

Tags: usa, census, population

I've been trying to find a good source that connects components of population change (births, deaths, migration) to the block level.

Whats the best source for this?

Comment: The answer is likely to depend on the time period over which you want to measure change. For example, if you want to measure change from one year to the next that may limit your options when it comes to data, compared to looking a change over decades. Since lots of data (e.g. from the American Communities Survey) are only released at block-group level, it might be useful to indicate if any geographies other than blocks would be acceptable.

Comment: I have found a good source for county level, and I suppose that is the best I can find. Thanks for the response though.